# Focus window created by PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, inputbox

I can display a simple Visual Basic inputbox from a PowerShell script like this:

```
$null = [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("microsoft.visualbasic")
$input = [microsoft.visualbasic.interaction]::inputbox($question, "bla", $text)
```

However, the inputbox window does not get focus which remains with the PowerShell window.

Is there a way to give focus to the inputbox window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could focus the InputBox from a job.

For example:

```
$null = [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("microsoft.visualbasic")
$activateWindow = {
        $null = [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("microsoft.visualbasic")
        $isWindowFound = $false
        while(-not $isWindowFound) {
            try {
                [microsoft.visualbasic.interaction]::AppActivate($args[0])
                $isWindowFound = $true
            }
            catch {
                sleep -Milliseconds 100
            }
        }
    } 

$job = Start-Job $activateWindow -ArgumentList "Unique Title"
$input = [microsoft.visualbasic.interaction]::inputbox("What is your answer?", "Unique Title", "none")
Remove-Job $job -Force
Write-Host $input -ForegroundColor Yellow
```

Comment: Did you try copying and pasting my code exactly as it is? If so, try placing `sleep 5` at the beginning of the job ScriptBlock, and see if the InputBox gets focus after 5 seconds. If I place the sleep at the beginning of the scriptBlock, I am able to manually activate some other window after the InputBox appears, and the job will reactivate the InputBox after 5 seconds.

Comment: Hey! It worked now. Don't know what I did wrong the first time... Ta.

Comment: Figured it out now. It doesn't work in PowerShell 1, which we use on servers. It does work in PowerShell 2, which I use on my PC.